# variable para modal en JS y PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, modal

Necesito hacer un modal para cada variable, tengo un modal en JS y no puedo mandar las variables de la BD a cada modal... el modal OBVIAMENTE con ese código toma el valor de la primera variable y NO puedo PENSAR como hacerlo que tome el valor de cada una de las variables al recorrerlas con el ciclo for..

cerebro apagado..!!

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++){ ?>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name=""></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos[$i]["id_entrada"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos[$i]["entrada_autor"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos[$i]["entrada_status"]; ?></td>
                <td><img id="myImg" src="../img-usuarios/<?php echo $datos[$i]["entrada_imagen"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $datos[$i]["entrada_titulo"]; ?>" width="300" height="300"></td>
                <td><button class="btnAdmin" id="myBtn" style="background-color: #2196f3"><i class="far fa-eye"></i> Contenido</button></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos[$i]["entrada_favs"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos[$i]["entrada_coment_count"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos[$i]["entrada_fecha"]; ?></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btnAdmin" style="background-color: #66bb6a"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Aprobar</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btnAdmin" style="background-color: #ffc107"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Desaprobar</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btnAdmin" style="background-color: #f44336"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Eliminar</a></td>
            </tr>


            <!-- CONTENT MODAL -->
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <p><?php echo $datos[$i]["entrada_contenido"]; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <!-- IMAGE MODAL -->
                <div id="imageModal" class="imageModal">
                    <span class="closeImageModal" onclick="document.getElementById('imageModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
                    <img class="modal-image-content" id="img01">
                <div id="caption"></div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: No pongas el codigo como foto sino como texto.

Comment: listo una disculpa ...

Comment: Como haces para abrir el modal?

Comment: con un script en el footer..

Comment: Deberias agregar el script tambien.

Comment: no me deja me dice que parece puro codigo que agrege mas descripcion... no se como ahora.. je

Comment: Utilizas el id `myModal` para abrirlo?

Comment: var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

Comment: Ese es tu problema, el id debe de ser unico.

Comment: si eso lo comprendo completamente pero no entiendo o no puedo razonar como hacer para hacerlo dinamico... llegue a un punto de no comprenderme lo que pienso!!!

Comment: no se si meto el script dentro de este archivo que es un php o lo dejo en el footer y como hago para que el id sea dinamico.. no se ... me atore ahi...

Comment: Usa un solo modal y al botón que abre el modal, agregas los datos como `data-atributo` de los que necesites mostrar en el modal; aprovechas el evento `show.bs.modal` para extraer los datos y mostrarlos en el modal. `$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})`

Comment: utilizas Jquery en tu codigo?

Comment: No JS puro eso es lo que me trae dando vueltas..

Comment: Usar un modal diferente para cada elemento que tengas, es una mala practica, lo ideal es tener un solo modal vacío que se llene según la opción que hayas solicitado, esto se puede hacer haciendo uso de AJAX

Comment: @JhonMaldonado exacto pero estoy perdido en el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript toma las IDs por lo que son, una ID debería ser única en todo tu DOM, al tu estar haciendo un for estas imprimiendo distintos modals pero con la misma ID siempre, por lo que al indicarle a Javascript que te muestre el modal con el ID #myModal este recorre el DOM desde arriba hasta abajo, encuentra el primer ID #myModal y lo ejecuta en él.

Solución rápida, puedes asignar distintas IDs a tu modal concatenandole la variable $i de tu PHP: id="myModal" y claro esta que tu enlace que realiza la apertura del modal debe también tener esta misma variable concatenada.

Comment: como resultado de lo que me comentas creo un modal para cada ID (excelente) pero el contenido se queda con la primer variable php y no cambia con cada id.. aunque este llamando atravez de php en el modal!!!
creo que me voy a rendir...!!

Comment: Hola @RoyGonzalez, rendir nunca, podrías compartirnos tu código nuevamente para ver cómo quedo y notar dónde estaría la falla?

Answer (score 0):

este es el boton donde tomo el id y mando pedir los datos de la BD

```
<td><button class="btnAdmin" id="myBtn<?php echo $datos[$i]["id_comentario"]?>" style="background-color: #2196f3"><i class="far fa-eye"></i> Comentario</button></td>
```

este es el modal dentro de el mismo codigo de php donde esta el boton para que recorra on un for junto con el boton

```
<div id="myModal<?php echo $datos[$i]["id_comentario"]?>" class="modal">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <span class="close">&times;</span>
                            <p><?php echo $datos[$i]["comentario_contenido"] ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

este es el script que esta incluso dentro del mismo php para que recorra los datos

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal<?php echo $datos[$i]["id_comentario"]?>");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn<?php echo $datos[$i]["id_comentario"]?>");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

me toma solo el valor del primer ciclo for y me muestra el resultado en todos los modales